# How can I use reflection in the Lambda expression in Java stream?

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, reflection, java-stream

I want to make it a common fuction to filter a list using a java stream.

 but it doesn't work out the way I want it to...

The code below doesn't work, but is it possible to filter using reflection within a lambda expression?

```java
 List filterList = commonList.stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getClass().getDeclaredField("metadata").get(this)
                .getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(this).matches(keywords))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 basic problems:

1. Lambdas may not throw checked exceptions and reflective methods throw them
2. Reflective methods are not typed; they have a return type of `Object`

You can however address both problems by employing a typed method that catches and rethrows as RuntimeException:

```
<T> getField(String fieldName, Object obj) {
    try {
        return (T)obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(obj);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Then use a typed call to tell the compiler that `name` is a `String`, like this:

```
List filterList = commonList.stream()
    .filter(x -> this.<String>getField("name", getField("metadata", x)).matches(keywords))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The easy way to code the method is using Lombok:

```
@SneakyThrows
<T> getField(String fieldName, Object obj) {
    return (T)obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName).get(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
x.getClass().getDeclaredField("metadata").get(this)
.getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(this)
```

returns an `Object`. There's no `matches` method declared in `Object` class. Imagine rewriting your lambda as:

```
filter(x -> {
    Object y = x.getClass().getDeclaredField("metadata").get(this)
.getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(this);
    return y.matches(keywords);
});
```

Thus the compilation error.

Also, `getDeclaredField` method can throw a checked exception, so it should be handled inside the lambda code:

```
filter(x -> {
    try {
        return x.getClass().getDeclaredField("metadata").get(this)
            .getClass().getDeclaredField("name").get(this).matches(keywords);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        //handle it here or re throw
        throw new RuntimeException("Error filtering the stream", e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to make it uglier, `getDeclaredField` would need a try-catch :(